# Combinatorics Problem - 25 different flags on 10 numbered flagpoles

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many ways are there to place 25 different flags on 10 numbered flagpoles if the order on a flagpole is a) not relevant? b) relevant? c) relevant and every flagpole flies at least one flag?

I'm not unsure how to start this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a$ you have a [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem where you have to have exactly $10-1=9$ dividers.  For b you multiply by the factorial of each component.  For c the Wikipedia article shows how to modify the number.